# Equation for Distance of the Straight line from the Origin.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

By reduction of the equation $ax + by + c = 0 $ of a straight line to the normal form , we get 
$$\left(\frac{-a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\right)x + \left(\frac{-b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\right)y = \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$$
And,
$$p= \frac{∣c∣}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$$
And my textbook says that $p$ is the distance of the straight line from the origin. I don't know why we are getting it as a distance from origin?

I know $p= x\cos\theta + y\sin\theta$ ( where $p$ is distance of line from origin).

Also I want to know how can we relate both equations?

Comment: Have you tried to check what's written about this [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line) or in other posts on this site like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85761/distance-between-a-point-and-a-line) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378903/axbycz-d-is-the-equation-of-a-plane-in-space-show-that-d-is-the-distance)?

Comment: @THE, you have made edits to about 30 questions in a matter of minutes, flooding the front page and driving other, newer questions off it. Please don't do that! Please edit three or four questions a day, not 30 in half an hour.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I knew that  soon something like that will come to me, and I appologise for what I did. But II did not took them from previous pages, they were already on the front page (Someone else had edited them), I just revised small mistakes.

Comment: @THE, yes, so I see. I have also left a comment for the other editor who is, if I'm not mistaken, a repeat offender.

Comment: Okay, @Garry, you do not need to worry shot it now. Nothing such will happen again from my side

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simple derivation of what you want to know. Without going into details, let me introduce the result:

> The perpendicular distance of a line $(Ax+By+c=0)$from a point is equal to $|\frac{Ax'+By'+c}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}|$. Where $(x',y')$ are coordinates of the point.

Since you want distance  of line from origin, the coordinates become $(0,0)$ and hence the perpendicular distance of a line from origin is $|\frac{Ax'+By'+c}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}|=|\frac{0+0+c}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}|=|\frac{c}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}|$.

Comment: I got that after few weeks I posted that. But I still don't know why $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$  is getting when divided by $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$

Comment: Wait, Have you got the book, SL Loney ??

Comment: Of coordinate geometry??

Comment: No :( I only follow my Textbook

Comment: Okay, then I m gonna send you pictures from that book of the section we are discussing here, I m sure it will help you, But where can I send you them ??

Comment: [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48921/the-jee-launchpad)

Answer (score 3):

Note that by [Cauchy Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), if $(x, y)$ satisfies $ax+by+c = 0$, then

$$c^2= (-c)^2 = (ax+by)^2 \le (a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2). $$

(The last inequality can be checked directly). Thus every points $(x, y)$ on the line satisfies

$$\tag{1} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ge \frac{|c|}{\sqrt{a^2+ b^2}}.$$

On the other hand, the point

$$(x,y)= \left(\frac{-ac}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, \frac{-bc}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$$

lies on the line and has distance

$$\frac{|c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

from the origin. Thus we are done.

Comment: I can't get  any thing from your answer, can you explain in any simple way?

Comment: Which part do you not understand, @Ramanujan?

Comment: After $-c = ax+by =$ to last

Comment: Please see the edit @Ramanujan

Comment: @JohnMa I suppose you wanted to write $(ax+by)^2 \le (a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)$ rather than $(ax+by)^2 = (a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)$...?

Comment: there is an error the point that lie on the line is  $(x,y)= \left(\frac{-ac}{a^2+b^2}, \frac{-bc}{a^2+b^2}\right)$
(withot the square roots of the denominators)

Answer (score 2):

For this derivation, we won’t be needing any trigonometric equation nor you have to prior study trigonometry.
For this derivation we just need the following things:

- Pythagoras Theorem
- Algebra
- Area of triangle $$\frac{1}{2} \times \text{height} \times \text{base}$$

Let us take the line equation $Ax+By+C = 0$.

So by putting first $y = 0$ solving for $x$ and then putting $x = 0$ and solving for $y$.

- By putting $y = 0$ and solve for $x$:
  \begin{align}
  Ax+By+C &= 0, \quad y = 0 \\
  Ax+B(0)+C &= 0 \\
  Ax+C &= 0 \\
  Ax &= -C \\
  x &= -\frac C A
  \end{align}
- By putting $x = 0$ and solve for $y$:
  \begin{align}
  Ax+By+C &= 0, \quad x = 0 \\
  A(0)+By+C &= 0 \\
  By+C &= 0 \\
  By &= -C \\
  y &= -\frac C B
  \end{align}

By doing the above we get the base distance and perpendicular distance of the triangle formed by the line equation $Ax+By+C = 0$.

Since the triangle formed is a right-angled triangle, we can get its area and hypotenuse with no problem.

- So first, deriving the hypotenuse:
  $$\text{Rise} = \left|\frac{-C}{A}\right|,\ \text{Run} = \left|\frac{-C}{B}\right|$$
  Pythagoras Thm.:  Hyp.${}^2$ = Rise${}^2$ + Run${}^2$:
  \begin{align}
  \text{Hyp.}^2 &= \left|\frac{-C}{A}\right|^2 + \left|\frac{-C}{B}\right|^2 \\
  &= \frac{C^2}{A^2} + \frac{C^2}{B^2} \\
  &= \frac{C^2(A^2+B^2)}{(AB)^2}; \\
  \text{Hyp.} &= \sqrt\frac{C^2(A^2+B^2)}{(AB)^2} \\
  &= \frac{|C|\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{|AB|}.
  \end{align}
- Deriving the Area:
  \begin{align}
  \text{Base} &= \left|\frac{-C}{A}\right|, \\
  \text{Height} &= \left|\frac{-C}{B}\right|; \\
  \text{Area} &= \frac 1 2 \times \left|\frac{-C}{A}\right| \times \left|\frac{-C}{B}\right| \\
  &= \frac{C^2}{2|AB|}.
  \end{align}

We can also write the area as half the hypotenuse times the height that is perpendicular to the hypotenuse (Note: the height perpendicular to the hypotenuse is the shortest distance to the origin, so let us call this height $w$).
\begin{align}
\text{Area} &= \frac 1 2 \times \text{hypotenuse} \times \text{perp. height} \\
\frac{C^2}{2|AB|} &= \frac 1 2 \times \frac{|C| \sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{|AB|} \times w \\
\frac{C^2}{|AB|} &= \frac{|C|\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}{|AB|} \times w \\
|C| &= \sqrt{A^2+B^2} \times w \\
\frac{|C|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} &= w.
\end{align}

This is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

By simple identification, the two equations are identical when

$$-\frac a{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\cos\theta,\\
-\frac b{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\sin\theta,\\
\frac c{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=p.$$

This is coherent as you verify $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$. If $c$ is negative, change all signs.

---

As one can verify by substitution,

$$x=p\cos\theta-t\sin\theta,\\y=p\sin\theta+t\cos\theta.$$ describes any point along the line, by varying $t$.

The distance from the origin to this point is given by, after simplification,

$$d=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt{p^2+t^2}.$$

The minimum value is indeed $p$.

Comment: How we get$x=p\cos\theta-t\sin\theta,\\y=p\sin\theta+t\cos\theta.$